# dual booting with windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 and partitioning

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have a current setup on my desktop PC using Windows 7 32bit

Currently, i have 2 partitions

**C:** for system files and programs installed

**D:** Here are all files such as videos, songs,ebook, etc

What I'm planning to do is to dual boot with Ubuntu 12.04

I'm new to Linux, so please bear with me. :)

I have some questions that really confuse me. I'm planning on having a clean install and dualbooting Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04

My Questions are:

- What's the best partition setup for a clean install of windows 7 and later on dual boot it with ubuntu 12.04?
- Do i need to have a separate partition for files on windows such as drive D: or just create a **media** partition that can be shared by both OS? if i do create a **media** partition wouldn't i have any conflicts in the long run?
- If ever i create a /boot partition would i make it **primary** or **logical**?
- Is there an **order** to follow in creating partition? For ex. Do i have to put the /boot partition before / (root) partition?
- where should i install the bootloader of ubuntu, so that when computer boots you have to choose between windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04.

Sorry, if i'll ask all my questions all at once. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install windows first. Go to start type Disk Management

Now shrink your windows partition to however space u want ubuntu to you. Right click and delete free space, you now have unpartitioned disk space.

Boot up the ubuntu cd and install ubuntu. It will automatically configure grub for you meaning when u boot up you will have a screen that says: ubuntu (auto selects this in 10sec), memtest, and windows.

Windows bootloader doesn't configure itself for linux, but grub does for windows so need not worry.